# How to revert a deleted commit in github

Tags: github

I deleted a commit in github when I did want to but I do not know how to bring it back. It just shows me it's history. (solved)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751837/git-can-we-recover-deleted-commits

Comment: yes but it was done in github. How can I revert it even though the project is not connected to my local machine using git.

Comment: If you do a "git log" it should still show the prior commit.  Then do a "git reset --hard [commit#]" and push it again.  Git is designed to allow for mistakes.